# Boostrap CSS - Change Table Border Colors

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

How can I also change the column borders in a HTML Table using Bootstrap CSS?

This is where I have gone so far:

**Boostrap Pre-Defined Table**

[image]

The table lays inside a jumbotron and I would like to change the table borders and lines so It can be more distinguishable. This is where I have gone so far.

[image]

As you can see, the table lines between columns remain the same. How can this be changed?

Any other suggestions on improving the Table Appearance are gratefully accepted

**table.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Employees</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Record</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**table.css**

```
.jumbotron{
    margin-top:250px
}

tr {
    border: 3px solid gray;
}
```

Code is now in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vagg77/o7paeymx/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
.jumbotron .table-bordered tbody tr {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.jumbotron .table-bordered tbody tr td {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.jumbotron .table-bordered tbody tr {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.jumbotron .table-bordered thead tr {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.jumbotron .table-bordered thead tr th {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2>Employees</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Record</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Jcode,probably your answer will be accepted. how can I add the JSFiddle inside a snippet? I tried to do it on the post but with no luck

Comment: No problem! Using the code below I was able to generate a code snippet.                                                                                 `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->  <!-- language: lang-css -->  //code here  <!-- end snippet -->`                                                                           Make sure the code is indented at least four spaces or use CTRL+K to auto indent. Sorry if this post is hard to read I'm on mobile lol.

Answer (score 2):

Add `border left` & `right` to `td` & `th`:

```
table td ,table th{
    border-left: 3px solid gray !important;
    border-right: 3px solid gray !important;
}


table td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Omi for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
   border: 3px solid gray !important;
}
```

Comment: please provide more details about your answer, its will be help for the future users

Comment: That what I did below @core114.

Comment: @saroyanm sir, yeah like you

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are not being able to set column border is because of the CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). 
Your rule is being overridden by more specific rules, the most specific one for `<td>` in your case is `.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td` which is set by the Bootstrap.
You have couple of options to how to deal with this situation:

## Use more specific rule

Write rule that will override the one set by Bootstrap, for example:

**HTML**

```
<table id="employees-table" class="table table-bordered">
  ...
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#employees-table td,
#employees-table th
{
  border: 3px solid gray;
}
```

## Use !important exception

Using [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) is considered to be a bad practise, but for your case it might be the most quickest/easiest solution:

```
table td,
table th
{
  border: 3px solid gray !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @saroyanm for the info!!! Your answer also applies to my table but I can only select one accepted answer :(